# using insert() and doing a bulk insert doesnt seem to trigger a insert with scout into Algolia

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-scout

I am doing a bulk insert in Laravel like

```
\App\Example::insert([
    [
        'name' => 'abc',
        'value' => '123',
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'def',
        'value' => '456',
    ],
    // etc...
]);
```

This will do a bulk insert, one query but still inserting many rows at once.

The problem is that when I use `insert()` the rows doesnt get inserted to Algolia. So how can I do a bulk insert to Algolia as well?

I dont want to loop through my rows and do a insert one by once since this will cost extra requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Laravel Scout` creates the `Algolio Searchable` on the `model::created` method.

[You can view that here in the source code](https://github.com/laravel/scout/blob/3.0/src/ModelObserver.php#L57).

As Laravel does not spawn the `created/updated/deleted` events on `Mass Events` this means that Algolio will never receive these as well.

One option to work around this would be to take the most recent auto-incrementing ID, then after the insert take that ID again, then call `->searchable()` on a filtered where clause on the relationship, like this:

```
 DB::transaction(function() {
    $currentId = \App\Example::max('id');
    // do the insert
    $lastId = \App\Example::max('id');

    \App\Example::where('id', '>', $currentId)->where('id', '<=', $lastId)->searchable();
 });
```

By using a `transaction` we ensure that we the `$lastId` wouldn't be corrupted by parallel queries. In this way, we have to perform 4 queries, which is still nominal compared to possibly dozens or more.

Truthfully you could probably simplify that code more.

Comment: But ``DB::transaction(`` wont lock that table completly? I mean if some other users does a insert it will affect the id. If I understood it right ``DB::transaction`` only rolls back if a exception is thrown

Comment: @user2722667 No. The point of the transaction, in this case, is to ensure that the last ID is not mutable by another parallel query. You can test it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call `->searchable()` on a model collection, as @Ohgodwhy mentions in the comments. The Algolia engine for Scout will batch the updates for multiple model instances together, keeping the overall number of requests low.

Comment: You can actually call `->searchable()` on a collection. So if you just use a simple `whereBetween`query with the ID's of the inserted data, you can just batch it that way. Super powerful, especially when `Scout` is configured to use `Queues`.

Comment: You're totally right. I somehow missed that in the source code. I'll update my answer.